# I am not able to get the response content from API call

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am doing a post request and reading the response as given

```
var response = client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.ToString(), Content).Result;
var value = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
```

if the result is a proper json string, it populates that in 'value' variable
otherwise it returns empty.

but if run the same in postman or fiddler i get this as response

[image]

Is there a way to get this response too?

Comment: You need to use `await`. Don't use `.Result`. You likely have a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadAsStreamAsync()` returns a `Task<System.IO.Stream>` and not a `Task<string>`. The json string that you see is probably the debugger showing you the content of the stream.

Consider using `ReadAsStringAsync()` to get the HTML content :

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.ToString(), Content);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: well it didnt work  as i still got empty text, but i used restclient code provided in postman. it worked alright. thanks though